# I sthere need to create different jars for jnlp of 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I am trying to execute jnlp on my 64 bit linux system and Jnlp code is
// For 64 bit system
  
// For 32 bit system
   
Is there any need to convert jars into 64 bit.I am not even sure whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is in the jar. If it's a pure zip of compiled .java code then it will be architecture independent.

However, if it contains native code (e.g. C or C++) then there's no automatic way to convert: you have to obtain x64 compiled versions of those, and, perhaps even change the java native interface code to load the appropriate native libraries.

So, in summary, either (i) the jar will work out the box or (ii) some recompilation effort will be necessary.